# C Client app that connects to a host and sends a reques

Tags: c, tcp, host, ipv4

I've got a problem in my client app. My requirements are that my app has to have a menu with 4 choices:

1. Connect to host
2. Disconnect from host
3. Send request "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
4. Close app

The connection has to be made using a host name and IPv4 and TCP protocols.
From my code below I think i have managed to connect to the host but whenever I try to send my request i get nothing in the console I think something crashes. I've tried searching everywhere but I can't find a solution.
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */
#include <stdbool.h> /* bool values */

int sockfd;

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

void connectToServer(char *hostname) {
    int portno =        80; /* set port number */
    char *host =        hostname; /* set hostname */

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    else printf("SUCCESS!\n");
}

void sendRequest() {
    char *message_fmt = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    int bytes, sent, received, total;
    char message[1024],response[4096];

    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    /*
     * if the number of received bytes is the total size of the
     * array then we have run out of space to store the response
     * and it hasn't all arrived yet - so that's a bad thing
     */
    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n", response);
}

void disconnectFromServer() {
    close(sockfd);
    printf("DISCONNECTED!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool exit = false;
    while(!exit) {
        int choice = 0;
        printf(" 1. Connect to server \n 2. Disconnect from server \n 3. Send request 'GET / HTTP/1.0\\r\\n\\r\\n' \n 4. Close application \n Enter selection:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                connectToServer("www.google.com");
                break;
            case 2:
                disconnectFromServer();
                break;
            case 3:
                sendRequest();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit = true;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Not a valid choice!! \n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried looking everywhere for answers but I couldn't find any. Anything I do I still get an empty console when I select option 3.

Comment: Your did not fill your `char message[1024]`

Comment: You saved my life, thanks! But now my problem is that the response i get is too big. Any solutions to that?

Comment: If you want to save the entire response into a variable, you will need to use `malloc` and `realloc`. If you just want to print the content. change the read loop to ```do {bytes = read(sockfd,response,total); if (bytes < 0) error("ERROR reading response from socket"); write(1, response, bytes);} while (bytes != 0);
```

Comment: Or just greatly increase the size of  `message`